# Filtering echo output based on content of a span

Tags: php, web-crawler

I don't really have experience with PHP so excuse me if I am not explaining myself properly.

We have a really simple crawler we found as a free resource, but we would like to make it a bit better:

When it finds and prints this div, within which there is a span with a class `price-ext`. I would like to filter the echo output using an `if` statement based on the contents of the span. If the span with class `price-ext` is equal to "v.o.n.", then don't print the div. If the content is anything different, then the `echo $post` can go through.

```
    <?php
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    $target_url="http://www.funda.nl/koop/heel-nederland/inbeeld/sorteer-datum-af/";
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($target_url);
    foreach($html->find('div[class=specs]') as $post)
{

    echo $post."<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why can't you analyse `$post` before `echo` inside `foreach` loop? It is possible to use regexp or functions like `strpos()`. What is the problem?

Comment: So far I have only tried the thing that ProfGhost also suggested but it doesn't work. I would guess its because its looking at $post rather than the span inside. I am currently looking at your suggestion for using `strpos()`, however I am not familiar with it so I am currently trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=specs]') as $post)
{
    if ( $post != "v.o.n" ) {
    echo $post."<br />";
    }
}
```

Should work if i'm not wrong.